# Where to put Groovy bean definitions in a Spring Boot webapp?

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot I can get a jar created with my webapp (allowing me to execute it as java -jar test-0.1.0.jar as I want).  I would like to configure the Spring beans using the groovy bean def syntax, with a separate file like beans.groovy that would contain the definitions.

How can I have that groovy file included in my jar and how can I tell Spring to load it?

I've seen a few examples around the web showing how to define beans this way together with spring boot, but none explain how to get that groovy file included in the jar and run as a webapp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SpringApplication` accepts `Resource` paths as sources, so just include a `String` ending in ".groovy", e.g.

```
public static main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run("classpath:beans.groovy", args);
}
```

Comment: Cool, that looks simple enough.  The only part I'm missing then is how to have the gradle build include the beans.groovy file in the jar file that it generates.

Comment: Gradle normally puts stuff from "src/main/resources" in the root of the classpath. Nothing Spring or Boot related there - you can roll it any way you want to.