# Spring boot does not load beans from groovy bean builder

Tags: spring-boot

I have been trying to create a simple springboot program that uses Groovy bean builder, but im missing something:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info "Starting MyApplication..."

        Object[] sources = [MyApplication.class, new ClassPathResource("bb.groovy")]
        SpringApplication.run(sources, args)
    }
}

//MyController.groovy
@RestController
class MyController {
    ConfigObject configObject
    MyService myService

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    String home() {
        return myService.getSomeData()
    }

}

//src/main/resources/bb.groovy
beans = {
    myService(MyService) {
        url = "http://www.spring.io"
    }

    configObject(ConfigObject) {
        new ConfigSlurper().parse("Config.groovy")
    }

    myController(MyController) {
        configObject = ref('configObject')
        myService = ref('myService')
    }
}
```

SpringBoot starts up fine, but I get a 404 at /home. I also dont see any attempt (sys out) in the startup to load the beans from bb.groovy

I know this is possible from the answer to [Where to put Groovy bean definitions in a Spring Boot webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060995/where-to-put-groovy-bean-definitions-in-a-spring-boot-webapp) but i must be missing something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. This is not an issue with spring boot, but with the bean dsl syntax.

It must be beans { }. Not beans = { }

Removing the equals sign loads the configuration fine. I was using the Grails way of resources.groovy, where the syntax is beans = {}

Also, in order to inject the Config.groovy, I had to use

new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config) instead of
new ConfigSlurper().parse("Config.groovy")

where Config.groovy is a file in the same directory as bb.groovy.

(Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cli-groovy-beans-dsl)